# Connect GitHub to tableau using JDBC

Tags: github, jdbc, oauth-2.0, tableau-api

I have been trying to connect Github to Tableau (to analyse my organization's repos) using Progress DataDirect JDBC connector according to this tutorial -> https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/connect-to-github-data-using-jdbc-for-your-analytics-and-reporting

I have no prior experience in Oauth2 and wanted to know what the

```
 "OAuth application name, Homepage URL, and Authorization callback URL"  should be for my use case?
```

[image]

More background:

I am using Tableau desktop on a windows machine.
If I use the "basic" method to connect to GitHub via the JDBC driver it does not seem to work (empty tables)

I have also tried connecting to GitHub via the [Web Data Connector for tableau](https://github.com/tableau/webdataconnector), but the queries I run return empty tables.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question.

Comment: Apologies , @MarkRotteveel. Ive edited the question